# how to upload service APK for existing android market applicaion using same google account

Tags: android

I have developed two different APK(as different projects).

One is Application APK and it is already on market, and another is service, which i developer just now and it is not on market.

So, How can I upload that service APK in that Google account, which i already upload application APK. 
Do I need to change package names? How about Key-store? Do I need to use same key-store or different key-store for different versions. And what about version number?

**- Thanks**

Comment: If it is diff package name then you should use another key store for sign the application apk also you can upload service apk try this.

Comment: I got the solution, I upload service as Another product